# Self-signed certificate change on Cisco3750

Tags: cisco, security

I'm running a script, that checks the configuration changes between the saved and running config.
I have noticed, that the hash that goes after

```
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-34586112
certificate self-signed 01
```

Has changed after a reboot.
Is it normal? Why does the hash change after a reboot?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is normal. On a Cisco device, a self-signed certificate is not persistent by default. In other words on every reboot it generates a new keypair and a new certificate.

To configure a persistent certificate see [Persistent Self-Signed Certificates](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2sr/12_2sra/feature/guide/srpkissc.html).